# dashed to/for the door

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

> She dashed to/for the door.

- Is 'dashed' natural here?
- Is there any difference between 'dashed to' and 'dashed for'?
- Is 'dashed' typically used when a destination is included or would it be just as natural to use it like this:

> She dashed down the hall.

Comment: Welcome to ELL SE! Please tell us what you found by looking up the word. Include some [learner’s dictionaries](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/739/11885) in your research, because they often include information and examples of how they are used, related idioms, etc. you can also search dictionaries of idioms. If you still have questions, edit your question here with more specific questions so we can better help you.

Comment: You can also search for “dash to” and “dash for”, etc., and see if you can quickly find useful information.

Answer (score 1):

Running *to* the door suggests that the door is the destination (perhaps to let someone in or to keep them out).

Running *for* the door implies an intention to exit through it.